# Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 without installing video drivers?

Tags: installation, drivers, video

So I have an old (got it FREE) laptop that my mom gave me after she spilled coffee on it. I was able to clean it and get it running Windows XP. I was only able to do this by letting it BSOD and getting into safe mode and disabling the video card in the device manager.

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 but I can’t seem to figure out how to disable the video card like I did in Windows. The install seems to go fine until the first reboot and then the background loads but no desktop icons and then I get the error messages and it asks me if my video card froze requiring a hard reboot.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: If you're having any issues at all with video drivers (or any drivers, for that matter,) I don't recommend using 12.10 at all. I tried it, but the frustration caused by drivers was just too much to bear. I know it doesn't really answer your question (that's why this is a Comment and not an Answer :P,) but I recommend, if you haven't already gotten settled into 12.10, to just download the 12.04.1 ISO and reinstall. (And this is coming from a serious beta tester - I use devs of *everything*, and use Firefox Nightly for my everyday browsing... I still hate 12.10...)